# How to control fans rpm manually on Intel DP43BF motherboard

Tags: motherboard, fan, speed

Wonder of how can I manipulate fans' rpm on Intel BP43BF motherboard manually? I've found in Bios only setting to disable automatic fan speed manipulation, but there isn't any way to set rpm speed. I've also tried SpeedFan, but with no success.

It's rather obsolete motherboard with 775 socket. I've managed to update bios to latest 0088, and still no opportunity. Appreciate any help.

Comment: purchase and use a fan controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... have you ever used Speedfan before (I know you mentioned it already)? It's a little complicated to get working, but once you do I believe it may be able to work even on a 775 mobo. I googled it and came up with some good guides:

http://unitstep.net/blog/2007/11/02/using-speedfan-to-automatically-control-your-pcs-fan-speeds/

Extra note:
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/249305-29-speedfan-controlling-speed

Comment: +1 , you got me at `"Hmmm"`.

Comment: @Joshua, so there isn't any tool for mobo? Previously I've simply set 40% of rpm in Asus mobo bios. But here it's more tricky.

Comment: No way would Intel have such a feature. Intel motherboards are almost always "stock" and come with no frills / special features. They are effectively reference designs which get used / built-upon by third-party motherboard makers such as ASUS, MSI, Gigabyte, etc. - all those guys add cool features and software. Speedfan is your best option with the Intel mobo.

Comment: @Joshua, and what if Speedfan still can't control fans speed. I've tested it for two days with different options. Could it be true that even speedfan can't control it?

Comment: YES . . . . . . .

Comment: Well, seem only external speedfan controller is only solution in my case, because I don't like MOBO internal one. It speeds up CPU fan on 100% when CPU temp is only 30C. That's ridiculous.

Comment: Confirming - SpeedFan has absolutely no effect on this board. I tried everything - DC, PWM control, every advanced option out there.